# Format cpu value in log file

Tags: java

i have a log file that has this format:

```
<id,date,cpuUsage,memoryUsage>
```

the cpuUsage is written in this way,`2.78667264E8` , how i can find the correct `%` of cpu on that value?

Comment: And what's the meaning of `cpuUsage` in that line?

Comment: cpuUsage = 2.78667264E8 , of an application

Comment: I know, but what's the meaning of that value?

Comment: i dont know what are u saying.. seriuosly.. the cpuUsage is used to determine the compsution of an app

Comment: Your app is consuming 278667264 of CPU? Is that the number of CPUs or percentages or bogomips? Look at the code that writes the log to find out.

Comment: Maybe that value is correct, but someone already multiplied by hundred? Should be 0.0278...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`2.78667264E8` is a correct value, not incorrect. It can be expressed in a different format, something like 278667264.00

To do that you need to use a `NumberFormat`

```
double num = ....;
NumberFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#0.00");     

// Prints with two decimals and without E notation
System.out.println(formatter.format(num));
```

Comment: i printed this `278667264,00`, and i'm still confused on the correct value to attribute.

Comment: E notation means your number multiply 10^(number after E) so.... 2.78667264E8 = 2.78667264 * 10 ^ 8 =  2.78667264 * 100000000 = 278667264

Comment: ok, i understood that, so given that number 278667264 how i can find the correct %?

Comment: I don't know what it means. This is just a formatter for your data. CPU Usage can be for example ms of cpu execution time from start of the system . Check the documentation of the library you used to get this value.

Comment: Perhaps there is another function cpuIdle. If yes you can retrieve the percentage as cpuUsage / (cpuUsage + cpuIdle). It returns a number between 0 to 1 (where 1 is 100%). If you like you can multiply by 100 and add the % sign (also using a formatter)

Comment: i can assume that cpuIdle could be a value betwenn 3/10? or i have to determine also this value?

Comment: No you need a function that returns it. Or you need to check the documentation to know what range of values can assume cpuUsage.